# Method to instantiate objects

Tags: objective-c

Would like to create a method that instantiate  objects.

```
- (NSArray *) make3Of : (Class) type
{
    ...
    type * temp = [[type alloc] ...
    ...
}
```

But I get a warning from Xcode ...

Actual warning: 
"Class method +alloc not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Is there a better/correct way to do this?

Actual code:

```
- (NSArray *) getBoxesOfType: (Class <ConcreteBox>) type StartingFrom: (uint64_t) offset
{
    NSMutableArray *valueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: nil];

    for (uint64_t i = offset; i< boxStartFileOffset + self.size; i += [self read_U32_AtBoxOffset:i]) 
    {
        if ([[self read_String_OfLen:4 AtBoxOffset:offset + 4] isEqual:[type typecode]]) {

            [[type alloc]initWithFile:file withStartOffset:i]; //warning here; 

            //yes I plan to assign it to a variable 
            //(originally of "type" but that won't work as AliSoftware pointed out, will be using "id" instead.

            ...

        }
    }
}
```

Same as example, I'm trying to instantiate a couple of objects.

Code for protocol:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ConcreteBox

+ (NSString *) typecode;

- (id) initWithFile: (NSFileHandle *) aFile withStartOffset: (uint64_t) theOffset;

@end
```

Comment: The question is not much clear. Please give the actual code, it should be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue with what you've provided. Can you provide the actual class definition and if possible the actual error your getting?

Comment: @MattWilliamson Clarified the error and added the protocol definition - everything else is pretty standard, the class is just a subclass of NSOBject. I think the compiler is afraid that whatever class I use as the argument during run-time won't have the +alloc method. Was wonder how do I do this "right".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a variable (in your case `type`)... as a type for another variable!

In your code, both `type` and `temp` are variables, that's a syntax error.

As you don't know the type of the variable as compile time, use the dynamic type `id` instead. This type is specifically designed to handle cases when the type is not defined at compile time.

So your code will look like this:

```
-(NSArray*)make3Of:(Class)type {
  id obj1 = [[[type alloc] init] autorelease];
  id obj2 = [[[type alloc] init] autorelease];
  id obj3 = [[[type alloc] init] autorelease];
  return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right about using "type" as a type for variable declaration - but I actually have not written that part yet; `[type alloc]` was already giving me trouble. But that still doesn't fix the "Class method +alloc not found (return type defaults to 'id')" warning.

Comment: Just tried in Xcode the exact code I put in my answer above and no warning here. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hmmm, you are right. It would seem the warning only appears if there is a protocol involved e.g. `(Class <ConcreteBox>)`. I have pasted the actual code into the question - should have done that initially but I was posting from the a smartphone.

Comment: You can't apply a protocol to a `Class` type, that's a metatype. The `Class` metatype doesn't conform to protocols, it represent class definitions (that may themselves conform to protocol). So the syntax you are using `Class<MyProto>` is not supported. Unfortunately AFAIK the only way to check it is at runtime (e.g. `if ([type conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProto)])`)

Comment: OK thanks. I must say, Objective C's loose typing is really starting to irk me.